# Калькулятор умножения и сложения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть калькулятор, не пойму как перемножить кол-во на стоимость курса затем сложиь значения всех полей и вывести в итого, подскажите плизз..

```css
.calculator {
  max-width: 990px;
  margin: auto;
}
.calculator__body {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.calculator__input.calc--border:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
}
.calculator__raschet {
    display: flex;
}
.calculator__center { text-align: center; }
.calculator__item {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}
    
.calculator__item:hover {
      background-color: #72cbf6;
  }
.calculator__item:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #ccded7;
  }

.calculator__itogo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.calculator__itogo span {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.calculator__itogo input[type="number"] {
      margin-top: 0;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
.calculator__btn {
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #0071a6;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.calculator__btn input {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

input.calc__input {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  &:last-child { border-top: none; }
  &:focus {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }

}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator__body">
    <table class="calculator__table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Список курсов</th>
          <th>Продолжительность</th>
          <th>Стоимость</th>
          <th>кол-во/чел.</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__item">Охрана труда при работах на высоте</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Охрана труда для руководителей и специалистов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Пожарно-технический минимум</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Повышение квалификации</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Повышение квалификации для работ на особо опасных объектах</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Профессиональная переподготовка</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Профессиональная переподготовка</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Оказание первой медицинской помощи</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator__center">
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">72 часа</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">112 часов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">256 часов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">512 часов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator__center">
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__item">3000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">2500 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">2500 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">4000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">5000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">15000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">20000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">4000 руб.</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator__inputs">
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input calc--border" type="number" value="">
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator__raschet">
    <div class="calculator__btn">Расчитать</div>
    <div class="calculator__itogo"><span>Итого:</span>
      <input type="number" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $price = $('.calculator__list:eq(2) li')
  var $count = $('.calculator__list:eq(3) input')
  var $result = $('#result')
  var $calc_btn = $('#calc_btn')
  
  $calc_btn.click(function(){
    var summ = 0
    $price.each(function(idx, item){
      price = parseFloat(item.textContent)
      count = parseFloat($count.eq(idx).val())
      summ += price * count
    })
    $result.val(summ)
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator__body">
    <table class="calculator__table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Список курсов</th>
          <th>Продолжительность</th>
          <th>Стоимость</th>
          <th>кол-во/чел.</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__item">Охрана труда при работах на высоте</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Охрана труда для руководителей и специалистов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Пожарно-технический минимум</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Повышение квалификации</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Повышение квалификации для работ на особо опасных объектах</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Профессиональная переподготовка</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Профессиональная переподготовка</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">Оказание первой медицинской помощи</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator__center">
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">72 часа</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">112 часов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">256 часов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">512 часов</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">---</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator__center">
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__item">3000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">2500 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">2500 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">4000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">5000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">15000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">20000 руб.</li>
              <li class="calculator__item">4000 руб.</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator__inputs">
            <ul class="calculator__list">
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
              <li class="calculator__input">
                <input class="calc__input calc--border" type="number" value="1">
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator__raschet">
    <button id="calc_btn" class="calculator__btn">Расчитать</button>
    <div class="calculator__itogo"><span>Итого:</span>
      <input id="result" type="number" value="">
```

Код конечно даже близко не похож на идеал как это должно было бы делаться правильно, но я отталкивался от приведённого примера.

Берём колонку с ценой за курс, вернее каждый элемент списка из неё, функция `parseFloat` позволяет выдернуть из текста число отбрасывая текст идущий после числа, затем по индексу сопоставляем с соответствующим полем ввода количества человек и перемножаем.

Comment: Спасибо ! Вопрос закрыт !